# the children of the class .row not have the same height

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4 using flexbox, I can not understand why my items are not the same size. the div on the left is larger than the div on the right. How can I solve it?

```
<div class="row mb-0 pb-0 d-flex" style="border:1px solid red;">
  <div class="col-sm-8 mb-0 pb-0" style="border:1px solid blue;">
    <div class="md-form mt-4">
      <textarea type="text" id="objetivo_especifico" class="md-textarea form-control" formControlName="objetivo_especifico"></textarea>
      <label for="objetivo_especifico">Objetivo Específico</label> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 flex-center" style="border:1px solid blue;">
    <a  class="m-0"     class="btn-pin waves-light animated mr-8 bola_roja p-0 m-0" >Holi
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eh98ugvs/

the second div that is a child of the .row class has height with respect to its size. I would like it to have the same height of the div with greater height, in this case it is the div on the left.

Comment: You're using the pre flexbox version of Bootstrap 4. Use the latest version, or a version later than alpha 6.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Bootstrap is 4.2.1. You are using alpha version, which means that it can be unstable and may come with lots of bugs, that are fixed in later versions. Flexbox was fixed and now the behaviour should be as expected.

For more infos check theif website https://getbootstrap.com

See the code snippet below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.css">

<div class="row mb-0 pb-0 d-flex" style="border:1px solid red;">
  <div class="col-sm-8 mb-0 pb-0" style="border:1px solid blue;">
    <div class="md-form mt-4">
      <textarea type="text" id="objetivo_especifico" class="md-textarea form-control" formControlName="objetivo_especifico"></textarea>
      <label for="objetivo_especifico">Objetivo Específico</label> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 flex-center" style="border:1px solid blue;">
    <a class="m-0" class="btn-pin waves-light animated mr-8 bola_roja p-0 m-0" >Holi</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you use the latest version of Bootstrap your columns will always have 100% height of the row. Sidenote, check the classes you add because some of them are not required, for example you don't need to add d-flex to row because row already displays as flex.